# Button not working discord.js discord-buttons

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, discord-buttons

hello so i write this code

```
module.exports.run = async (Client, message, args, prefix) => {
 
 if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
  disbut(Client);
  let button1 = new disbut.MessageButton()
    .setStyle("green") //default: blurple
    .setLabel("créer un channel") //default: NO_LABEL_PROVIDED
    .setID("create"); //note: if you use the style "url" you must provide url using .setURL('https://example.com')
  let button2 = new disbut.MessageButton()
    .setStyle("red") //default: blurple
    .setLabel("fermer un channel") //default: NO_LABEL_PROVIDED
    .setID("close"); //note: if you use the style "url" you must provide url using .setURL('https://example.com')

  message.channel.send("Cliquer sur les boutons pour effectuer une action   ", {buttons : [button1, button2] });
};
```

if i execute my command the texte is send in my channel but not the button
and i dont understand why and i dont have any error

thanks for your help :)

Comment: I got it in the docs for adding multiple buttons here is how: `let row = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(button, button2);`. and then send buttons `send('msg', row)` with a message. give it a shot.

Comment: And you returning content that hasn't prefix 2 times. What is the purpose of doing that?

Comment: Thanks you for your answers i will try that as soon as possible         And for your question i just miss misclick my ctrl-c ctrl-v.

Comment: and my promblem is not to add multiple button , i cant add just a single  button on my message

Answer (score 1):

In Discord.js v13, the [`send`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) method only takes a single parameter. Discord.js is only looking at `"Cliquer sur les boutons..."` and not the second object you are providing.

Instead, use a single [`MessageOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions) object:

```js
message.channel.send({
  content: "Cliquer sur les boutons pour effectuer une action   ",
  buttons: [button1, button2]
});
```

For more information, see [this section in the Discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#sending-messages-embeds-files-etc).